# Problem with SSL while deploy Reverse Proxy on Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, reverse-proxy

After deploy Reverse proxy on Docker I got error and container with proxy not cannot get up. I am getting the error below:

**SHA:!DSS") failed (SSL: error:140E6118:SSL routines:ssl_cipher_process_rulestr:invalid command error:140E6118:SSL routines:ssl_cipher_process_rulestr:invalid command)**

I made reverse proxy from https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-nginx-reverse-proxy

Comment: This looks like a cut-off error message where the begin is missing. Please provide the full message. Also note that the instructions you followed have line breaks where they don't belong. Which means that your configuration will be messed up.

Comment: proxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list("ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-
proxy_1  | DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:
proxy_1  | AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-
proxy_1  | CBC3-SHA:!DSS") failed (SSL: error:140E6118:SSL routines:ssl_cipher_process_rulestr:invalid command error:140E6118:SSL routines:ssl_cipher_process_rulestr:invalid command)

Answer (score 7):

The instructions you follow are broken. The `ssl_ciphers` configuration line is broken into multiple lines instead of having everything in a single line with no spaces in the cipher string. Just cut and paste from the instructions will result in the problems you see.

Moreover, better don't follow these instructions anyway. These are outdated. Specifically the given settings disable the modern TLS 1.3 protocol which is a bad idea. Better follow the instructions from the [moz://a SSL Configuration Generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx)